# How to pass scope value to the directive controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hai i am trying to pass array of scope value from controller to the directive how it possiblbe.

i need to pass this value to my directive controller                 `$scope.recipientsOrgIdArr.push(data.relatedEntityInstanceId);`

HTML file

```
<search  searchobj="tei_org"  selecteditemslist="recipientsOrgIdArr"   searchid="organisation" />
```

Search Directive

```
.directive('search', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'AEC',
        scope: {
            selecteditemslist: "="
}
link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
console.log(scope.selecteditemslist);  // getting as undefined

//how can i get scope value here
}
}
})
```

please help me to solve this problem thanks in advance

Comment: Most probably when the directive link function is called the array recipientsOrgIdArr is not filled. Use a watch in link function to know when the array gets data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're experiencing is that `selecteditemslist` has not yet been set by the time your directives link function is called.

Try this

```
.directive('search', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'AEC',
        scope: {
            selecteditemslist: "="
        }
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            scope.$watch('selecteditemslist', function(value) {
                if(value){
                    console.log(scope.selecteditemslist);
                }
        }...
```

Answer (score 0):

try using this code:

```
    .directive('search', function ($timeout) {
        return {
            restrict: 'AEC',
            scope: {
                selecteditemslist: "="
    }
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
    attrs.$observe('selecteditemslist', function(value) {
    console.log(value);
  });
    }
    }
    })
```